# CakePHP - Including ACL component gives fatal error: ConnectionManager::getDataSource - Non-existent data source

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, acl

I'm trying to figure out ACL, and so I'm trying to work through the tutorial in the book (Cake 1.3, by the way).

I've created the database tables (aros,acos,aros_acos).  As soon as I try to include the Acl component in my AppController, however, I get a fatal error when I try to access any page:

Fatal Error (256): ConnectionManager::getDataSource - Non-existent data source  [CORE/cake/libs/model/connection_manager.php, line 102]

In my AppController:

```
    public $components = array('Auth','Session','RequestHandler','Acl');
```

Removing Acl from the components array makes everything work again.

The errors disappear when I comment out some code in my AppController.  Here is the code - the lines commented out are the culprits.  AppModel::slugList() is a custom function that just does a find query based on a slug.  It works fine, at least until Acl is included.

```
        if ($this->modelClass != 'Country'){
            $this->loadModel('Country');
        }
        if ($this->modelClass != 'Category'){
            $this->loadModel('Category');
        }
        $this->Session->write('Country',1);
        $this->Session->write('City',1);
        $_countryId = $this->Session->read('Country');
        //$_countries = $this->Country->slugList();
        $_cityId = $this->Session->read('City');
        //$_cities = $this->Country->City->slugList();
```

**Edit** - also, three notices appear:

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 813]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 838]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 841]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had a model called "Permission" that my model "Role" that actsAs an Acl requester was related to.  This was the problem.  I guess the Acl component uses a class with this name somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by an inconsistency between your models and/or the database table structure.  The key to debugging it is the set of notices.  Inserting a var_dump statement on dbo_source.php::line 813 will give you a hint as to where your break is located.  Example:

```
foreach ($model->{$type} as $assoc => $assocData) {
    $linkModel =& $model->{$assoc};
    $external = isset($assocData['external']);

    var_dump($model->name, $assoc);
    if ($model->useDbConfig == $linkModel->useDbConfig) {
        if (true === $this->generateAssociationQuery($model, $linkModel, $type, $assoc, $assocData, $queryData, $external, $null)) {
            $linkedModels[$type . '/' . $assoc] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, I had a model defined for a database table I had forgotten to create.